# Blazor Server fails to logout user when cookies expire (AWS OIDC)

Tags: authentication, cookies, amazon-cognito, openid-connect, blazor-server-side

**Goal:**
Blazor Server closes a circuit when cookies expire, deletes all cookies and kicks user out of the website (redirects user to identity provider).

**Notes:** 
I am using Blazor Server and AWS Cognito OIDC for authentication.

**Problem:** 
I encountered this bug when cookie's ExpireTimeSpan has passed, the connection to the server will be disconnected showing "Attempting to reconnect to the server: 1 of 8" and all cookies will be deleted, after a moment the connection will be established again **BUT** the user will be on the same page and still can navigate and perform actions, and new active cookies generated for the user.

Program.cs

```
app.MapBlazorHub(option =>   
{  
    option.CloseOnAuthenticationExpiration = true; //This option is used to enable authentication expiration tracking which will close connections when a token expires  
});
```

Statup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
    options.Cookie.MaxAge = options.ExpireTimeSpan;
    options.SlidingExpiration = false;
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(ConfigureOpenIdConnect);
```

OIDC configuration

```
private static void ConfigureOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectOptions options)
{
    // Main OpenID Connect settings
    options.MetadataAddress = _Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:MetadataAddress"];
    options.ClientId = _Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = _Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:ClientSecret"];
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    options.ResponseMode = OpenIdConnectResponseMode.Query;
    options.SignOutScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.UsePkce = true;
    options.SkipUnrecognizedRequests = true;
    options.SaveTokens = true;

    // Scope
    options.Scope.Clear();
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("phone");
    options.Scope.Add("aws.cognito.signin.user.admin");

    // Events
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
    {
        // SignOut
        OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut,

        // Access Denied
        OnAccessDenied = context =>
        {
            context.HandleResponse();
            context.Response.Redirect("/");

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },

        // ChallengeAsync
        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
        {
            context.ProtocolMessage.Prompt = "login";
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
}

private static Task OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut(RedirectContext context)
{
    context.ProtocolMessage.Scope = "openid";
    context.ProtocolMessage.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress =
        $"{_Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:LogoutEndpoint"]}?" +
        $"client_id={_Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:ClientId"]}" +
        $"&logout_uri={context.Properties.RedirectUri}";

    // Delete cookies
    context.Properties.Items.Remove(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    // Close OpenID session
    context.Properties.Items.Remove(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Best regards x